# in Behat, Is there a way to test for a specific tag?

Tags: behat

I have a function in my FeatureContext.php that uses @AfterScenario to clean up fake database entries created during the test.  I'd like to add a @debug tag to a particular scenario tell the function to NOT delete the entries created for that scenario if the tag is present.

```
/**
 * Deletes the records created during the scenarios.
 * @AfterScenario
 */
public function cleanDB(AfterScenarioScope $scope)
{
    // if !@debug present
        // delete files from database
    // end if
}
```

Comment: What version of behat?

Comment: Didn't tried with tags, but it should work to get the scenario title, or to set some variable and decide based on that.

Comment: @lauda, Behat 3.1

Comment: Have you seen this? https://github.com/Behat/Behat/issues/703

Comment: @lauda, you want to post a formal answer based on that and get credit before I do? :)

Comment: Is ok, you can post your solution, i just helped with some info, i only gave directions and not an actual solution. Glad that i could help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@lauda's answer got me close and I figured out the rest.

I used the hasTag() function of Behat's scenario object.

```
/**
 * Deletes the NCP records created during the scenarios.
 * @AfterScenario
 */
public function cleanDB(AfterScenarioScope $scope)
{
    // if the @debug tag is set, ignore
    if (!$scope->getScenario()->hasTag("debug")) {
        // delete records from database
    }
}
```

If I decorate the scenario with @debug, I can test for that and change my functionality.

```
@debug
Scenario: do the thing
  ...
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the tags are set on the feature.  You've got to do something like:
`in_array('debug', array_merge($scope->getFeature()->getTags(), $scope->getScenario()->getTags()));`

Comment: @hackel there is a hasTag method: $scope->getFeature()->hasTag(...)